# Can I construct a trigger that deletes existing rows before inserting new ones in SQLite, which lacks FOR EACH STATEMENT?

Tags: trigger, insert, sqlite, delete

Here’s my SQLite schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deps (
    target TEXT NOT NULL,
    user TEXT NOT NULL,
    dependency TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS targetUser ON deps (target, user);
```

In words, the `deps` table (a dependency tree) is intended to have multiple 
rows for each `(target, user)` pair—all rows with the same `(target, user)` pair are dependencies of `target` for some `user`.

In my application, a user only *batch*-updates the dependencies of a target. By “batch” I mean that I would (1) `DELETE` all rows containing the `(target, user)` and then (2) `INSERT` the new rows fresh.

I would like a trigger to combine these two steps in the SQLite database, so that before I insert new rows for a given `(target, user)`, the database deletes all old rows for this pair. I came up with this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS clearOldDeps BEFORE INSERT ON deps
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM deps WHERE target = NEW.target AND user = NEW.user;
    END
```

but alas! SQLite triggers are all `FOR EACH ROW`, and it lacks `FOR EACH STATEMENT`, so if I use this trigger above and insert some rows for a given `(target, user)` pair, each row inserted deletes the rows that were inserted just before!

Observe:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO deps VALUES ("t1", "u2", "e1"), ("t1", "u2", "e2"),("t1", "u2", "e3");
sqlite> select * from deps;
t1|u2|e3
```

I went to add three rows, and wanted any pre-existing rows for `("t1", "u2")` target–user pair to be deleted, but I only got the last row inserted, because it deleted all previous ones.

If SQLite had `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers, I suspect this trigger could be made to work using that, but since it doesn’t, is my only recourse to first `DELETE` then `INSERT`? Is there any more concise way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that this is a *lite* version of SQL and does not support all operations. See the following link:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

SQLite supports a **BEFORE TRIGGER** which can delete rows before further action is taken. The link also provides some cautions about how that works:

> If a BEFORE UPDATE or BEFORE DELETE trigger modifies or deletes a row
>   that was to have been updated or deleted, then the result of the
>   subsequent update or delete operation is undefined. Furthermore, if a
>   BEFORE trigger modifies or deletes a row, then it is undefined whether
>   or not AFTER triggers that would have otherwise run on those rows will
>   in fact run.

See the link to learn other details about the SQLite triggers.

Of course you could write your SQLite code to **delete the rows that you no longer need** in your database **before inserting new rows** into your database. I would **prefer that approach** over a trigger since your are just getting rid of unwanted data.